# How auto is deducing pointer type?

Tags: c++, pointers, auto

In below code I could not understand how `auto` comes to know that thing on right hand side is pointer :

```
int x = 100;
int *ptr = & x;
auto test = ptr;
std::cout<<*test<<std::endl;
```

Because as per my understanding pointer contains address which is nothing but `unsigned int` so how `auto` deduces it to be pointer but not `unsigned int`?

Comment: _pointer contains address which is nothing but unsigned int_ . That's wrong.  An address is not necessarily an unsigned int.

Comment: _The type of a variable declared using auto is deduced from its initializer_. That's all.

Comment: so here initializer is ptr so how it come to know that it must be pointer and not other type

Comment: `auto` is evaluated during compilation time, **not** during runtime, so it makes no difference what value the "pointer contains" (not really sure what this expression even means).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can also ask the question "eventually, everything in my program is bytes, so why does `auto` doesn't deduce everything to be `uint8_t[]`?"

Well, it's simple. the type of `ptr` is `int*` so the type of `test` is also `int*`. it doesn't matter how the generated assembly looks like. it may be that the cpu treats `int*` and `unsigned int` the same way, but that's irrelevant for C++, as C++ is a **high level language**.

besides that. the underlying statement that "a pointer is an unsigned int" is not true. pointer is a type that allows reading and writing to the memory address contained in that variable. an unsigned int is ... an unsigned int. nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: but same thing doesn't work for references if ptr is int& then test is int why ?

Comment: @Kapil this is a different, unrelated question.

Comment: @Kapil That's just how auto type deduction works. You would have to use `decltype(auto)` to get `int&`.

Comment: @David Thanks understood your answer and comments

Answer (score 3):

The standard says:

> The type of a variable declared using auto is deduced from its initializer.

Thus, the type of `test` is deduced from the one of `ptr` (that is *its initializer*) and it's `int *`.

Note that `auto` follows almost the same rules of template type deduction.
You can refer to them for further details about the differences between `auto`, `auto&`, `const auto &`, `auto&&` and so on.

Comment: so just curious to know that if its only from initializer then why those 4 bytes are considered as pointer but not unsigned int or some other type

Comment: @Kapil because the type of `ptr` is `int*` and not `unsigned int`.

Comment: so you mean to say auto goes back and check declaration and from that deduce that ptr is int* so test should also be int*

Comment: @Kapil in most cases, yes